# Drop Down Issue in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing a issue  regarding dropdown overlapping in IE7(Snapshot attached). I am using bootstrap css  and js for dropdown purpose. I have read articles regarding it over net. I have increased z-index for the dropdown also tried with the position attributes, but it went in vain.

[image]

Comment: z-index should worked.. how you tried ??

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: I have set  select box position relative ,z-index 1.Also I have set the position of dropdown absolute,top 100%,left 0 and z-index 3.But this doesn't work IE7.